QGIS Graphical Modeler: Dropdown list of strings based on fields values from another Layer
I have a graphical modeler where I need to type the name for a desired region as a string and extract some data matching the name of the region from an layer of another geopackage.
In the following example I will type the desired region by hand as a string in this case 'Buchhofen'. Then the model searches for the external layer F_75003_KommunalesGebiet in the geopackage by_basisdlm_plus.gpkg where the input string matches the field of the external layer "BEZ_bezeichnung".
I am looking for a way to change the manual input ( remove error made by the user writing the region false / or not remembering the places name in first place) by providing a drop-down list with all the (2227) entries from the field "BEZ_bezeichnung" from the layer F_75003_KommunalesGebiet.
Any idea how this can be implemented?
Is there maybe a native way of doing it without writing an additional script?

There is the ENUM-Input but unfortunately the different entries must be added by hand, one by one and this would not be an option for this particular example because I have over 2000 entries. Furthermore I would have to process the answer and create an very long case-when for reading the selection by index and converting it again to its original value (string)

